# Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral with $M \in AD, N \in BC$

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral and $M \in AD, N \in BC$ such that $\dfrac{AB}{CD}=\dfrac{AM}{MD}=\dfrac{BN}{NC}$ and $BA \cap CD=P$. Prove that the angle bisector of $\angle BPC$ and $MN$ are parallel.

I wanted to prove this geometrically, yet I don't know how to tackle this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "prove this geometrically"?

Comment: @CalvinLin Proving with the help of a diagram and some constructions on it, not just using coordinate algebra.

Comment: Are you saying that P is an intersection of BA an CD?

Comment: I assume that you mean "bisector of angel..."

Comment: @Moti Yes, the $\cap$ represents the intersection between the two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be so that $ABCF$ is a parallelogram and $CE$ the angle bisector of $\angle FCD$:

[image]

It follows that
$$DE:FE = CD:FC = CD:AB = DM:AM$$
so $EM\parallel FA$, and
$$EM : FA = MD:AD = MD:(MD + AM) = CN:(CN + NB)$$

That shows $EM$ is parallel and equal to $CN$. It follows that $EMNC$ is a parallelogram, or $MN\parallel CE$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it really helped me out.